# how to test barcode scanning while developing a application in c#

Tags: c#, vb.net

I am developing an application which will be used to scan the barcode from a particular document, as i am just developing who i will get know that barcode scanning is working i dont have device at the moment, can you please guide me about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating our barcode controls I just bought a cheap USB scanner to test with locally. You can get a basic one for ~$50 that will give you an idea of what to expect.

While faking the input can be useful for unit testing, using a real device is a must for robust code. You'll find that the quality of the printed barcode, the paper, quirks of the scanner, etc. will reveal potential bugs that you'll never find with hard coded barcode data.

This is also why I recommend getting a cheap one - it is the most likely to exhibit odd or less than reliable results which you'll need to accommodate unless you require your customers to use a very specific model which you verify works elsewhere.

Answer (score 3):

Usually the barcode scanner will act like a normal input device (like a keyboard).  It will return a number and hit enter.

Barcode scanners can act differently depending on it's settings.  But they are usually configurable.

Comment: For example, I am  developing an application, i need to check either bar code scanning is working or not i dont have barcode scanner though